# Custom ordering of mixed integer and strings in dataframe index

Tags: python, html, pandas, datatables

I have a Panda's Dataframe that I need to reindex into a specific fashion. There are several numbered indices, but the last one is a string. Without the inclusion of the string, the index goes in numerical order, 1-20 just fine.

However, as soon as I include the string index, the order switches to alpha-numeric (1, 11, 12... 18, 19, 2, 20, 3, 4, etc.). Is there any way where I can organize the list properly numerically, then add on the string index without changing how the list is organized?

[EDIT]:

Realized the shortcoming on my own part. I thought I had included that the data frame was being converted to an html-safe table ( *[DataTable](https://www.datatables.net/)* ) after construction and being displayed on a web page. It is possible this might be causing the issue I am having, though any insights to this matter are welcome.

An example of the kind of data frame I am looking at:

```
          Column 1
0       Value 1
1       Value 2
2       Value 3
3       Value 4
    ...
18      Value 19
19      Value 20
string  Value 21
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```
new_index = list(df.index)

new_index[-1] = 'string'

df.index=new_index
```

For example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(5))

>>> df
          0
0  0.665922
1  0.591298
2  0.274722
3  0.561243
4  0.382927

new_index = list(df.index)

new_index[-1] = 'string'

df.index=new_index
```

returns a re-indexed df:

```
>>> df
           0
0       0.665922
1       0.591298
2       0.274722
3       0.561243
string  0.382927
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want, though this puts the string index as the first row in the resulting table rather than as the last as shown in your example. I tried something similar by getting a list of the index and appending the string I needed, but it results in the same row location.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. You can separate out numeric and non-numeric indices and sort them independently.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4', 'Val5']},
                  index=['0', '1', '11', '2', 'string'])

order1 = sorted((x for x in df.index if x.isdigit()), key=lambda i: int(i))
order2 = sorted(x for x in df.index if not x.isdigit())

df = df.loc[order1+order2]

#            1
# 0       Val1
# 1       Val2
# 2       Val3
# 11      Val4
# string  Val5
```